# what is the fastest way of getting table record count with condition on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

As per subject, i am looking for a fast way to count records in a table without table scan with where condition

Comment: Could you explain a bit further please?  Are you just looking for:
select count(*) from tablename 
Perhaps with a "with (nolock)"

Comment: I ahve larga table that i need to select count of records. Say 

select count(id) from users where active=1

I am looking for a way to count records without full table scan, i've found  some samples that gets all records count from sys indexes  but not sure if it is possible with condition

Comment: @nLL: you should edit your question to add this extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, ensure that your table is correctly indexed for the where condition.

If you're concerned over this sort of performance the approach is to create indexes which incorporate the field in question, for example if your table contains a primary key of *foo*, then fields *bar*, *parrot* and *shrubbery* and you know that you're going to need to pull back records regularly using a condition based on *shrubbery* that just needs data from this field you should set up a compound index of [*shrubbery*, *foo*].  This way the rdbms only has to query the index and not the table. Indexes, being tree structures, are far faster to query against than the table itself.

How much actual activity the rdbms needs depends on the rdbms itself and precisely what information it puts into the index.  For example, a *select count(*)* on an unindexed table not using a where condition will on most rdbms's return instantly as the record count is held at the table level and a table scan is not required.  Analogous considerations may hold for index access.

Be aware that indexes do carry a maintenance overhead in that if you update a field the rdbms has to update all indexes containing that field too.  This may or may not be a critical consideration, but it's not uncommon to see tables where most activity is read and insert/update/delete activity is of lesser importance which are heavily indexed on various combinations of table fields such that most queries will just use the indexes and not touch the actual table data itself.

ADDED: If you are using indexed access on a table that does have significant IUD activity then just make sure you are scheduling regular maintenance. Tree structures, i.e. indexes, are most efficient when balanced and with significant UID activity periodic maintenance is needed to keep them this way.

Comment: Thanks. My table will have alot of insert/delete activity (around 50k-60k a day) waht would you advice heavy index? I know you explained on second part of your reply but i don't get it properly (english is not my native language )

Comment: 50-60k a day's not a lot. There's 86400 seconds in 24 hours, so taking 60,000 that's less than one change a second (assuming this app is in use evenly throughout the day). What are the peak hours? Are there any times the app is not used?

Without knowing table schema, patterns of use, etc saying whether a given index is good or not can't be done. 

General advice: keep the number of indexes on the table to a minimum, and the number of columns in that table to only those that are essential.

Comment: @rangerchris - keep number of indexes on the table to a minimum - amen to that, it just arriving at the most effective set of indexes for any particular set of circumstances which is the difficult bit, and that minimum is by no means always 1.

Answer (score 2):

There are different methods, the most reliable  one is

```
Select count(*) from table_name
```

But other than that you can also use one of the followings

```
select sum(1) from table_name

select count(1) from table_name

select rows from sysindexes where object_name(id)='table_name' and indid<2

exec sp_spaceused 'table_name'

DBCC CHECKTABLE('table_name')
```

The last 2 need sysindexes to be updated, run the following to achieve this, if you don't update them is highly likely it'll give you wrong results, but for an approximation they might actually work.

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE ('database_name','table_name') WITH COUNT_ROWS.
```

EDIT: sorry i did not read the part about counting by a certain clause. I agree with Cruachan, the solution for your problem are proper indexes.

Answer (score 2):

The following page list 4 methods of getting the number of rows in a table with commentary on accuracy and speed.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/07/15/sql-server-how-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table.aspx

This is the one Management Studio uses:

```
SELECT CAST(p.rows AS float)
FROM sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS idx ON idx.object_id = tbl.object_id and idx.index_id < 2
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.object_id=CAST(tbl.object_id AS int)
AND p.index_id=idx.index_id
WHERE ((tbl.name=N'Transactions'
AND SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)='dbo'))
```

Comment: Link is dead (10 years and counting :) )